# Compute the Integral of $z_t^{(n)}=\sum_{i\geq0}2W_{t_i^n}\mathbb{1}_{]t_i^n,t_{i+1}^n]}(t)$ w.r.t. the Brwonian Motion $W_s$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, quadratic-variation

Let $z=2W$, where $W$ is a Brownian Motion.

For $\{t_0^n,t_i^n,...\}=D^n$ (enumeration of dyadic partition), it is possible to show that the processes $$z_t^{(n)}=\sum_{i\geq0}2W_{t_i^n}\mathbb{1}_{]t_i^n,t_{i+1}^n]}(t)$$ converge to $W$ in $\mathscr{H}^2$, where $$\mathscr{H}^2:=\{z | z \text{ measurable adapted stochastic process },E\int_0^T|z_t|^2dt\lt\infty\}$$

We have $$\int_0^tz_s^{(n)}dW_s$$
$$=\sum_{i\ge0}(2W_{t_i^n}(W_{t\wedge{t_{i+1}^n}}-W_{t\wedge{t_{i}^n}}))$$
$$=\sum_{i\ge1}(W_{t\wedge{t_{i+1}^n}}^2-W_{t\wedge{t_{i}^n}}^2)-\sum_{i\ge1}(W_{t\wedge{t_{i+1}^n}}-W_{t\wedge{t_{i}^n}})^2$$
$$=W_t^2-QV_t^{(n)}(W)\rightarrow{W_t^2-t}$$
where the convergence is in $L^2$ and $QV$ stands for Quadratic Variation.

**Question**:
I get stuck on the second equality of the computation, how do we come to the third line.
If i have calculated correctly, the second line is equal to$$\sum_{i\ge1}(2W_{t\wedge{t_{i+1}^n}}W_{t\wedge{t_i^n}}-2W_{t\wedge{t_i^n}}^2)$$
and third line $$W_t^2-\sum_{i\ge1}|W_{t\wedge{t_{i}^n}}-W_{t\wedge{t_{i-1}^n}}|^2$$
for me it's **not clear why these two parts are equal**.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me understand it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have calculated correctly. The limit of $\sum_{i\ge1}|W_{t\wedge{t_{i}^n}}-W_{t\wedge{t_{i-1}^n}}|^2$ is the quadratic variation of $W_t$ which is $t$. So where is the problem?  It could help a lot if you number your equations using `\tag{}`.

Comment: @KurtG.Hi, Kurt. I have problem with this equation: $$\sum_{i\ge1}(W_{t\wedge{t_{i+1}^n}}^2-W_{t\wedge{t_{i}^n}}^2)-\sum_{i\ge1}(W_{t\wedge{t_{i+1}^n}}-W_{t\wedge{t_{i}^n}})^2$$
$$=W_t^2-QV_t^{(n)}(W)$$, why are they the same.

Comment: The first sum is telescoping and collapses to $W_t^2.$ The $QV$ term is just an abbreviation for the second sum.

Comment: oh, you are right, i didn't notice that it's telescope sum. Thank u so much!